# What is the relationship between two meanings of the word "astringent"?

Tags: meaning

The adjective **astringent** has two meanings ([Merriam - Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astringent)):

1. Causing contraction of soft organic tissues: styptic, puckery
2. Suggestive of an astringent effect upon tissue: rigidly severe: austere; also : pungent, caustic

To illustrate, the image corresponds to the first meaning is this:

[image]

And the one for the second meaning is this:

[image]

Is there a relationship between them?

Comment: Put some astringent in your mouth.  What do you sense?

Comment: I have never tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the meaning pungent, incisive is just a later firurative usage of the original "draw tight" suggesting the idea of something
stern, austere; as, "an astringent type of virtue:"

[Astringent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=astringent):

> - 1540s, from Latin astringentum (nominative astringens), present participle of astringere "to bind fast, tighten, contract," from ad- "to" (see ad-) + stringere "draw tight".  As a noun from 1620s.

(Etymonline)

[Astringent](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/astringent):

> - You know that vinegar-like liquid teens put on their faces in order to tighten their pores and dry up their pimples? That's astringent. ***An astringent personality, on the other hand, is perceived as bitter and perhaps even a bit toxic.***
> - Astringent may be a lifesaver for an acne-prone teen, ***but when the term is used as an adjective and applied to you personally, it's less positive. Since astringents are acid-based, an astringent personality can also be corrosive***. If someone is prone to biting sarcasm and cynicism, he probably has an astringent view of the world.

(Vocabulary.com)